# How to drop down box variable printing?

Tags: excel, vba, printing

this is my first post and I am very new to VBA in excel so I was hoping someone could help.

I've crated a spread sheet for the school I work in that generates a student report depending on a drop down box variables and I wanted to be able to print all the reports at once. there is a good 200 odd of them so I can't really do it one by one.

I have found this code and I think I've got it to work other than the actual printing part of it. I don't know what it means by add some "print page code here"

Can anyone help !?!

```
 Sub Iterate_Through_data_Validation()
Dim dvCell As Range
Dim inputRange As Range
Dim c As Range


'Which cell has data validation
   Set dvCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")
'Determine where validation comes from
   Set inputRange = Evaluate(dvCell.Validation.Formula1)

For Each c In inputRange
    dvCell = c.Value
    'add some print page code here
Next c

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

if your reading this I think I worked it out

This is what I'm using now!

```
Sub Iterate_Through_data_Validation()
Dim dvCell As Range
Dim inputRange As Range
Dim c As Range


'Which cell has data validation
   Set dvCell = Worksheets("Comb Student Report").Range("B4")
'Determine where validation comes from
   Set inputRange = Evaluate(dvCell.Validation.Formula1)

For Each c In inputRange
    dvCell = c.Value
    'add some print page code here
    ActiveSheet.PrintOut
Next c

End Sub
```